# Font size in matplotlib

Tags: python, fonts, matplotlib, font-size

In the following example, I have 7 x-axis labels. The 1st label is '60m' and the remaining are 1/12th degree ... 1/2 degree. However in the resulting figure the size of 60m is appropriate (16), but the others are much smaller. How do I fix it?

```
xtck = ['60m',r'$\frac{1}{12} ^\circ$',r'$\frac{1}{6} ^\circ$',r'$\frac{1}{4} ^\circ$',\
        r'$\frac{1}{3} ^\circ$',r'$\frac{5}{12} ^\circ$',r'$\frac{1}{2} ^\circ$']
xtickNames = pyplot.setp(ax1, xticklabels=xtck)
pyplot.setp(xtickNames, fontsize=16)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because all you other ticks are `mathtext` except the first one, the easiest fix is to  use `mathtext` for the first one as well, such as:

```
xtck = ['$60m$'.......
```

Now they will be of the same style.

'60m' should appear somewhat larger in the end, as the others are fractions.

If you are trying to force the `60m` to appear as the same size as the others, change it manually by adding this line in the end:

```
ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels()[0].set_fontsize(10) #10/16 is almost the Golden ratio
```